# Expire offer after a few minutes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, scheduled-tasks

In my Asp.Net MVC 5 website, I have an entity called `Offer` with an expiration time. For instance once an offer is started, it will be expired after 30 minutes. What I need is some way to set the status as `Expired` and email the owner of the offer to notify that their offer has expired.

What I found out so far are:

1. Using an endpoint on my website which tells the website to find expired offers and do this for all of them, then calling that endpoint from a Windows Service.
2. Same as above but using a scheduler library (instead of Windows Service)
3. Using scheduler for each offer. Meaning when I create an offer, add a scheduler entry for that specific offer.

None of these seem ideal so I'm asking here, looking for a better alternative. If there's none, which one would you go for?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the offer server-side, set an expiration timestamp and remember it (persist to a DB, etc). If someone attempts to redeem their offer after that time has passed, say it's expired. You don't need to actively track whether each individual offer has expired (unless you want to show the remaining time in the UI, in which case a little JavaScript can count down to the expiration timestamp).

Comment: Everything you said is true. However, as mentioned, I want to notify the owner of the offer via email that their offer has expired. The offer might not be checked during that time.